# How to clear an input on focus the first time?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 inputs:

```
<input type="text" value="username">
<input type="password" value="password">
```

I want to delete the default value (just the first time) if i'm in a specific input. I have add attribute with JavaScript like this:

```
onfocus="this.value='';"
```

But this it clear the input every time focused on it. How to clear the input just the first time focus on it ?

Comment: What you want is called a placeholder.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is called a placeholder : a default value that is automatically removed.

If you can accept your placeholder being [not visible for IE9- users](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder), do this :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="username">
```

If you need to be compatible with IE9, use [one of the many polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder), people have taken care of the implementation details for you.

Answer (score 6):

Just use placeholder in input, for example

```
<input type="text" placeholder="username">
```

It's good to give name for every input, so:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
```

Comment: Why is it good to give a name in the era of AJAX ? I think none of my inputs in the last 3 years had a name.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
onfocus="if(this.flag == undefined){ this.flag = true; this.value=''; }"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put a check on your onfocus function

```
    onfocus="if(this.value == 'username'){this.value='';}"


<input type="text" value="username" onfocus="if(this.value == 'username'){this.value='';}">
    <input type="password" value="password" onfocus="if(this.value == 'password'){this.value='';}">
```

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fernR/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can use this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="username" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('input[name=username]').one('focus', function() {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

`.one()` Will only fire the bound event once

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
$('.text').focus(function() {
    if (this.value == this.value) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if (this.value == "") {
        $(this).val(this.value);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/32Tns/296/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="username" id="username" title="username" />

$( '#username' ).bind({
    'focus': function( event ) {
       $( this ).val( '' );
    },
    'blur': function( event ) {
       var obj = $( this ),
           title = obj.attr( 'title' );
       obj.val( title );
    }
})
```